# How to create a stylesheet which complies with CSS3 standards

Tags: css

I am not quite sure how to create a new / modify my current stylesheet so that it complies with CSS3 using the new selectors etc...

My current stylesheet does not take some new selectors such as `border-top-right-radius: 5px;` as properties it simply ignores it.

Anyone know how I could use these new CSS3 features?

Comment: It's a vague question. There is no specific answer to that. Consider going through the list of new CSS3 features first, see what's been added and use them accordingly.

Comment: To begin with, there is no “CSS3” as a standard even in a lose sense, just documents labeled CSS3, ranging from sketchy or abandoned drafts to W3C recommendation. The question mentions “new selectors” but mentions just one *property*, and it does not explain what “these new CSS3 features” are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might need a prefix to the property to make it run on different browsers as they not all share a standard way of implementing these features.

```
#yourCssRule{
-webkit-border-top-right-radius: 5px;
-moz-border-radius-topright: 5px;
border-top-right-radius: 5px;

border-style: solid;
border-width: 2px;
}
```

To make changes visible you will have to give some width to the border and maybe some color too.

When it comes to Border Radius property I like to use this small tool that generates the prefixes for you http://border-radius.com/

Answer (score 2):

Not all browsers take properties like the one you're mentioning. It all depends on the browser (not all browsers support CSS3 either). Example:

```
-webkit-border-radius: 10px;
-moz-border-radius: 10px;
border-radius: 10px;
```

You use -webkit and -moz for WebKit and Mozilla compatible browsers, even if the standard one (according to CSS3) is border-radius. That's just because not all browsers use CSS3 standards. They will, eventually, but not now.

You can include the three lines I wrote, but it's not considered standard and it will fail verification (but still works).

Answer (score 2):

Like others said, there is no such thing as a "CSS3" or "CSS2" stylesheet. There's only one CSS stylesheet standard, and you can put CSS1, 2 or 3 properties and selectors in it.

What changes is browser support. Some new properties and CSS selectors will only work in more recent browsers.

I recommend you see by yourself at http://caniuse.com/. You can see there which CSS3 properties and selectors are widely supported and which ones are not.

I would also recommend you have a look at this : http://cssprefixer.appspot.com/. While it won't help you with unsupported selectors, it will add browser-specific prefixes to CSS properties in your file which might not be fully supported in most browsers.